# Java properties file in .jar folder

Tags: java, properties

I'm creating a basic app in Java and I'm using a `.properties` file but when compiled the solution the properties file is not included with the `.jar`.

How can I add the properties file to the `.jar` file?

This is the structure of my project:

[image: project]

What I did is just add a properties file like this:

[image: properties file]

I'm using netbeans 8.0.2, the file is in the same folder of the `.java` file but I need it in the `.jar` folder too

Comment: How exactly are you compiling the solution?

Comment: im using netbeans only doing clean and build

Comment: Please give more information about your project arborescence.

Comment: hi i edited the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To copy a file (config.properties) into target directory (dist/), you can modify your build.xml:

```
<target name="-post-compile">
    <copy todir="${dist.dir}">
        <fileset dir="" includes="config.properties"/>
    </copy>
</target>
```

To package properties file in jar itself, you can just put the properties file into the same directory as your source files. In this case, you can use Class.getResouce() to read it at runtime, but one has to re-package jar to modify it. Source directories are listed under "Source package folders" in project -> properties -> sources.

Comment: My properties file is created in the main folder of the project and the jar files is in the dist folder, to test the jar ,  have I have to put the properties file  in the dist folder by hand every time?

Comment: thanks this is what I want

Comment: just modify a little the code <copy todir="${dist.dir}">
   <fileset dir="" includes="config.properties"/>
  </copy>

Answer (score 0):

That depends on the IDE / build tool.

Generally, place the properties file into the root source folder. That can be something like `/src/main/resources` (Maven style) or `/src` itself (Eclipse style), and then recompile.

I don't know the NetBeans layout, but probably similar.